# Volumes and Entrypoints

Tags: codeship

I have a volume declaration in a service:

```
volumes:
  - .:/var/www
```

The service's container uses an entrypoint shell script to prepare resources (npm install and gulp build).  It runs fine in Jet but the files created by the entrypoint aren't ever detected when it runs for real.

What is different about volumes on the actual service?

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference between your local environment and the remote environment is that the build machines are created new every time.

Locally, you probably have npm modules and build files. Remotely, however, you won't have access to those. A way to test this with jet, is to download the repository and run directly  without any initial build processes - just `jet steps`.

#### Container Files

```
- var
  |- www
     |- node_modules
        |- //installed modules   
     |- build
        |- //build files
     |- src
        |- //source files
```

#### Build Machine Files

```
- root_folder
  |- src
    |- //source files
```

The difficulty with volumes during the container runtime is that what ever is in your root directory will override what was created during the image build.

The volume mapping remotely is, in most cases, unnecessary. You want to test the container in complete isolation.

I would recommend removing the `volumes` directive in the `codeship-services.yml` file - this should solve your issue.